# Chat login broken?

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat, login

I, for some reason can't login to the SO chats, at all. The page that lists all the rooms show's me as logged of, but when I try to log in, the page just refreshes, hitting log in in the chat room, just refreshes the page, too...

E1: Error 500 on https://chat.stackoverflow.com/

currently happens with the following browsers: latest Chrome dev-m & MS Edge

Comment: Can you clear the browser cache? Which browser? Any errors in the dev console? Are you using the site over http or https?

Comment: Same thing after cache clear. Latest Chrome dev-m build. No errors in rooms, but the overall listing yields a happy error 500. Http, did try https but that redirected to http :/ @rene

Comment: On which url is that 500 error? That is relevant, please [edit] it into your post

Comment: Can you try a different browser?

Comment: Same symptoms on edge.

Comment: Are you using a Google/Facebook or Stack Exchange account?

Comment: Google login. @rene

Comment: I can't repro here. Can you add request/response header info from that 500 error?

Comment: You never managed to login into chat, right? Does the console show any extra errors?

Comment: I see no specific headers for the request of the 500 error page. I also see no extra errors.

Comment: I'm out of ideas. This needs a dev to look at some server side logs.

Comment: Looks like you get the cookies I would expect. Not sure why it fails with an 500.

Comment: Just a note - the issue still persists.

Comment: Issue still remaining.....

Comment: If you don't have new info or can better explain what sets your local network setup apart from others I don't have high hopes to get it solved. If you do have more info please edit your question. Maybe using a local proxy like [fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/download/fiddler) will reveal anything useful. You could try to [contact  the team](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/contact) but don't expect them to diagnose and/or provide customer support to fix your localized issue as not many (AFAIK you're the only one) other users have the same problem.

Comment: @rene I've now switched operating systems, and the issue still persists on the new system, also I've verified that I cant log in the mobile page too, via te SE app.

Comment: I almost suspect your ISP is causing the issue.

Comment: 2 different very big ISP's aswell, that'd be a big coincidence. Also, my mobile carrier is a 3rd company.

Comment: I almost would suspect you're chat banned. But that is also something that  can only be confirmed by the team. Contacting them is your best option.

Comment: I have done so via the link you provided. Hoping they will reply sometime.

Comment: @rene On the other hand though - wouldn't that produce a clearly stated error? Would seem logical to do so.

Comment: I have never been chat banned, so I can't possibly know ;) but yeah, I wouldn't expect a 500. However, I don't think many users hit that code path often nor will developers so there is a chance they have a regression somewhere. Login in on the other hand is used by many users daily. A system-wide problem with that would have been noticed, making your case extraordinary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like there was a stray old chat profile that didn't get cleaned up correctly when you deleted your SO profile some time ago.

I took care of it, so you should be able to access chat now and a new chat profile will be created for you, linked to your current Stack Overflow user id.

I'm sorry about the delay in resolving this. Happy chatting!

Comment: I have seen this happen a handful of times before. Is there a way to detect the other account if the login fails? Or is manual detection the only option for these types of accounts?

Comment: @TravisJ Easy to detect, potentially hard to automatically determine what to do about it since the symptom doesn't necessarily tell you the whole story.

Comment: Confirmed working. Thanks!