# Can't log in to chat after a profile merge

Tags: support, chat

I am facing a similar issue mentioned in this [question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/317819/chat-login-broken). I am able to log in to Stack Overflow, but not in chat. 
As mentioned in the answer, I recently unified two logins. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I fixed up your profile. Unfortunately, it looks like your list of favorite rooms was lost in the process. On the upside, there were only two, so hopefully it's not too annoying to find them again.

Please let me know if you're running into any other issues with accessing chat.